# listview get the old item data which had scrolled out of the screen

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to know which item is scrolled out in the ListView?

I'm displaying some network images in the item, and I want to cancel the downloading job after the item is scrolled out of the screen.

Is there anyway of getting the old item's data when reusing this old item view?

Thanks :)

Comment: Use Universal Image Library or Picasso libraries which automatically cancel for over scroll if you are using GET method.

Comment: take a look at some image loader (from volley or Universal Image Loader) code(or use it) ... it is already done there ...

Comment: Definitely use Picasso, its very simply to get up and running and will take a lot of pain and suffering out of your life, trust me. See http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: But how would the image loader lib know some thread is being scrolled and can be canceled? I think they should provide cancel method and let me decide whether to cancel the job or not?